# Chances of serving time if I rob a store

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

If your chances of apprehension for committing some crime are 0.7 .the chances of being convicted if apprehended are 0.6 and the chances of serving time if convicted and apprehended are 0.5 .then find the probability that you will serve time if you rob the local grocery store. 
I could not understand that the probability of serving time is already given as 0.5 .then why do we need to calculate serving time probability for robbing a grocery store. It should be 0.5 too.

Comment: It is only $0.5$ if you are convicted and apprehended.

Comment: Then P(robbing a store) =0.7 It'll be p( serving time if apprehended and convicted of robbing the store) =0.5

Comment: You have 3 events that need to occur consecutively in order to serve time. You need to first be apprehended, second to be convicted and third to actually serve time. This is why you need all three numbers.

Comment: All you need to know surely is that Crime Doesn't Pay!

Comment: "*Then P(robbing a store)*"  No, the probability that you rob a store isn't mentioned anywhere in the problem.  $0.7$ is the probability that you are apprehended given that you committed some crime.

Comment: One way to think about the problem would be to imagine $100$ people who have robbed stores. If $0.7\cdot 100 = 70$ of them get apprehended, then...

Comment: In symbols... you are given $Pr(B\mid A)=0.7, P(C\mid B\cap A)=0.6$, and $P(D\mid C\cap B\cap A)=0.5$.  You are tasked with finding $P(D\cap C\cap B\mid A)$ which expands via multiplication principle as the product of the previously mentioned numbers.  Remember that $Pr(X\cap Y) = Pr(X)\cdot Pr(Y\mid X)$.  Do not confuse the probability of serving time given that you robbed a store, got caught, and got convicted with the probability of getting caught, getting convicted and serving time given that you robbed a store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is the event you are apprehended, $C$ is the event you are convicted, and $S$ is the event you serve time, the "story" gives $pr[A]$, $pr[C|A]$ and $pr[S|A,C]$, and you want to compute
$$
pr[A\cap C \cap S] = pr[A] pr[C|A] pr[S|A,C] = .7 .6 .5.
$$
You are saying something like, ``$pr[S] = .5$ if $pr[S|A,C]=.5$'', which isn't true.

Comment: Thank u for helping 

Answer (score 1):

The probability of serving time **if you commit the crime, are apprehended, and convicted** is 0.5.  But the question is about the probability of serving time if you commit the crime. If you commit the crime the probability of being apprehended is 0.7 and if you are apprehended the probability of being convicted is 0.6 so if you commit the crime the probability of being apprehended **and** convicted is (0.7)(0.6)= 0.42.  And if you commit the crime the probability of being apprehended, convicted, **and** doing time is (0.5)(0.42)= 0.21.

(Hmmm, that ain't bad.  Are you considering this as a career path?)

Comment: It might be better if you don't show the final answer in your post so the OP has to make the effort and so that it doesn't encourage people using the site to do their homework.

Comment: No. Not a career path .thanku for helping I am practicing to improve and score more. Thank u for helping. 